# Can anybody recommend a program that generates a graph the lines of code count?

Tags: php, real-time, lines-of-code

I've found a lot of programs and scripts for counting the number of lines of code using Google, but what I'm looking for is something that graphs it in real time. I'm hoping this will motivate myself and other programmers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I personally use [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) to keep statistics on all projects I maintain.

> StatSVN retrieves information from a Subversion repository and generates various tables and charts describing the project development, e.g. timeline for the lines of code, contribution of each developer etc. The current version of StatSVN generates a static suite of HTML or XDOC documents containing tables and chart images.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Really looking for something I can throw at small (one file) projects as well as larger ones without the hassle of SVN. Any other recommendations.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any other recommendations.

Comment: Have you found that it gives you an incorrect number of lines of code when you have deleted documents in SVN?  If so, do you know how to resolve this issue?  On this page http://wiki.statsvn.org/User%20Manual.ashx it says "Lines of Code counts will be inaccurate for deleted or moved files".